# Algorithm to find random [0,1]-1 pairing from a preexisting n-n relationship (if one exists)

Tags: algorithm, graph, set, relationship

All I can find on Google is "stable marriage" and so on, but these do not describe what I want.

**I have this as an input**:

```
A - 2, 3, 5
B - 1, 4, 2
C - 2
D - 1, 5, 4, 3
```

I want to **randomly (this is really important for my case)** select one of the elements on the right side for each element of the left side. But: There can be **no repeats**, however, elements from Set 2 (right side) **are allowed to have no partner**.

**Valid example output:**

```
A -> 3
B -> 1
C -> 2
D -> 4

The fact 5 is not represented anywhere is okay.
```

**Invalid outputs:**

```
A -> 2
B -> 1
C -> 2
D -> 4

Because A and C both go to 2
___

A -> None
B -> 1
C -> 2
D -> 4

Because A has no partner
__

A -> 4
B -> 1
C -> 2
D -> 5

Because A doesn't "like" 4.
```

I realize this will not have an answer for every initial state.
Is this a known problem with a known solution / proven to be unsolvable?

Edit: The randomization doesn't have to be "good" per se. As long as it "reasonably" doesn't produce a similar looking outcome every time (when it can be helped, at least), that's good enough for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far except googeling for a soloution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another hour of googling and falling down a graph theory rabbithole, I have found a github repo with a modified version of the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm:

https://github.com/slaypni/randomized-hopcroft-karp

It's in TypeScript which is a language I don't know, but it exactly solves my problem. So I will try to wrap my head around the code.

Edit: I managed to recode the whole thing line by line in Python. So this is solved for me now